# On mouseover click radio button in previous div

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble causing the click event. (note: The html is hardcoded and cannot be edited directly).
I am trying to trigger a click on the radio button in the previous div when the user hovers over the label.

```
    <div class="donation-level-input-container form-input">

    <div class="donation-level-label-input-container">
        <input type="radio" name="level_standardexpanded" id="level_standardexpanded2489" value="2489" onclick="evalMatchingGift('');">
    </div>

    <label for="level" onclick="" class="active">

        <div class="donation-level-label-container">
        $75
        </div>


    </label>

</div>
<script>
$('label').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).prev().find('input').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6jp244p9/. Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: Are these elements being created dynamically? Are you sure you're including jQuery properly?

Comment: Nevermind, the issue was that I have multiple labels and inputs which i didn't include here. I think I have it figured out now.